# calling any function on OnDisconnectedAsync Task in signalr Hub

Tags: .net, ajax, .net-core, signalr, signalr.client

English is not my first language
I have problem with client side implementation of signalrHub.
when i call removeConnectionID from connection.start()...
ajax call executes and takes me to Test action
but when i call removeConnectionID from connection.on("diss", ...
(OnDisconnectedAsync)
nothing happens and i dont get any errors
This is my ChatHub hub

```
 public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {


        // Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);
       
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        
       await  Clients.Client(GetConnectionId()).SendAsync("diss", Context.ConnectionId);
      await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
```

}
and here is my js code

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/chatt", {
    accessTokenFactory: () => "testing"
})
.build();


connection.start().then(function () {
connection.invoke('GetConnectionId')
.then(function (connectionId) {
   //alert(connectionId);
   removeConnectionID(connectionId);
})

}).catch(err => console.error(err));

 connection.on("diss", function(connectionId) {

     removeConnectionID(connectionId);
    //console.log(connectionId);
});

async function removeConnectionID(id) {
    await  $.get("/Chat/Test") ;
    }
```

I tried sending console.log to all clients from connection.on("diss", ...
(OnDisconnectedAsync) and it worked fine 
and tried to call same function from connection.start() and function works.
i think problem is that hub closes connection before action is done but dont know how to fix it!

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no **async** OnDisconnectedAsync. Remove async code mark.